# Floor paint stripping

Tags: paint, floor, removal, hardwood

OK, so I decided to strip a heavy black paint and what not on top of it from the hardwood floors in a 100+ year old house I purchased recently. To that end I purchased a $150 stripping tool ("Bauer") and used it on the floor (alas this tool is meant for stripping paint from metal, like cars, etc). Days later of pure pain and suffering, two ripping drums spent ($32 each) and a big grocery bag full of dust, I got to what I call the first approximation of cleaned floor. In those days, I am told, people used any material available for their construction. Judging by the smell, at least some planks are pure pine wood, but maybe not all. I want to lightly stain the wood (so the wood pattern shows) and varnish it. I also need to solve the problem of protruding nails...
Does anyone have a better solution for ripping these floors? I have 3 more rooms of this size (about 150 square ft) painted in that thick, heavy black color. I dread going through the same process -- very loud (even with headphones), dusty and physically very demanding. I do not want to use chemicals, for those just make the problem even worse. [protruding nails[image: flor ripping]

Comment: Did you test the paint for lead first?  100 year old house probably has some lead paint in it.  Lead is harmful for young children if it is in tiny particles, cause by sanding/ripping and is eaten/breathed in.

Comment: +1 on the checking for lead based paints- especially the way you are doing it with so much non-contained dust and fine particles. Stripping these floors "by hand" is going to be a whole lot of messy, difficult work. I have done this before with a belt sander an it is as you described. This would normally be done by a wood flooring guy with a big stand up drum sanding machine  that has integral dust collection (still a mess, but less physically demanding). Possibly available from a rental company in your area? If it helps, it is looking pretty good where you have done already. :)

Comment: Well, I am guilty as charged, I do not check for lead. Any time we hear of the lead dangers, my family reminds me that, as a kid growing up in Europe I was melting lead (on a stove) and pouring it into cardboard cones (in wet sand) making weights for fishing. Those little balls you put on a fishing line were made of lead and we closed them on fishing lines by our teeth. Since I was a child prodigy in science and math at a time, the joke is that imagine how much smarter I would have been if I did not inhale (and eat) all that lead...

Comment: Kyle, the job is rather demanding. I put on a rain poncho (which is heat collector), double "covid" mask, googles and "headphones" and then I press on the floor keeping at it. The first approximation is done, I will do some touch ups, but, as I said, I am not looking forward to doing the same with other rooms. Yes, my first thought was to rent a big bazooka from Home Depot, but the question is how effective it is. If I knew it would do the job I would use it. I think though that, on this hard paint that is almost cemented, it would not work...

Comment: Those big sanders are usually meant for hardwood and still need to pay attention you don't sand too deep/gouge in one place.  Would like to practice in a spot that does not matter as much to get a feel of them, but they should do the job.  With lead as most bad things it is the amount over time that that counts.

Comment: You need to punch down all the nails first - that way your sander lasts longer. If you can't see them because of the paint thickness, then it's a hands & knees job, waving a small, powerful magnet.

Comment: @Tatsujin I posted another photo showing the nails that got exposed after sending, but only 1 photo is showing likely because I do not know how to upload multiple photos. The second question is how you "tame down" those nails and the surrounding area of the planks so that they do not pop up or such. I think the particles I got from sanding the planks could be mixed with wood glue and then holes be filled in...